# Matching files using wildcards

Tags: regex, unix, diff

I have a script that tests some APIs that I am designing. This script takes the output of the program, and compares it to the expected output (Master file). If they match, then it returns no errors. I want to be able to mask out things like dates, memory addresses, etc.

Here's an example:

```
==== MASTER file ====
TEST STARTED ON .*
ADDING ELEMENT 5 to HASHTABLE. Location 0x.*
LOOKING UP ELEMENT 5. SUCCESFUL.
REMOVING ELEMENT
==== END ====
```

And a file to match it with:

```
==== OUTPUT file ====
TEST STARTED ON NOV/23 12:18
ADDING ELEMENT 5 to HASHTABLE. Location 0x51F56E2
ROOKING UP ELEMENT 5. SUCCESFUL.
REMOVING ELEMENT
==== END ====
```

Is there a way to ask `diff` to use these wildcards? Or is there any other program that does this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the order of lines in the OUTPUT file has to match with order of patterns in MASTER file? If not, `grep` may be more suited to this job. If yes, a custom shell script involving `grep` may be more straightforward than `diff`.

Comment: Humm yes, they should match. For now I separated the lines with useful information from the lines containing dates or memory locations - That way I can just ignore the troublesome lines with ```diff```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with a simple diff. You could do something like this though:

```
set -f
while IFS=, read pattern match ; do
  grep "$pattern" >/dev/null <<<"$match" || { echo ERROR ; exit 1 ; }
done < <(paste -d, master output)
```

Assuming `master` is the master file and `output` is the output file.

There are several important things to keep in mind:

1. The master file should contain regexps, so all lines should start with a `^`.
2. `set -f` is necessary to disable shell expansion, otherwise unintended consequences may arise.
3. Regexps should be properly escaped since they are called through variable substitution, thus needing double quotes.
4. `$IFS` must be set to a character neither used in the master file nor in the output file. Set `paste`'s `-d` paramenter accordingly.